# Get exit status of piped commands in PHP

Tags: php, bash

I've got a PHP script that calls the system shell with a piped command. In this case we're talking about a backup script (but it could be anything, I'm asking specifically about the exit status!):

```
exec(
    "mysqldump --user=$u --password=$p --host=$h --port=$p $db | gzip -9 > backup.sql.gz",
    $out,
    $status
);
```

Now I want to know if the mysqldump command yielded an error, but the `$status` variable always seems to contain `0`, even if I force an error. It appears to be the exit code of the **second** command (gzip in this case). I want to be able to see the exit status of the **first** command in PHP.

Comment: Why not execute them in series? Would be easy to tell then.

Comment: @e4c5, How in the world are the questions even *similar*? I'm asking about exit statuses, not about backups. The example script just so **happened to be** a database backup script.

Comment: @Machavity, I don't want a huge intermediate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a little help from the Bash internal array `PIPESTATUS`. This holds the exit status of each command in the pipe. Since you're looking for the first command's exit status you would be addressing `PIPESTATUS[0]`. So you're code would look like:

```
exec(
    "bash -c 'mysqldump --user=$u --password=$p --host=$h --port=$p $db | gzip -9 > backup.sql.gz; exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]}'",
    $out,
    $status
);
```

Note, this changes the overall exit status of the `exec()` call and you'll need additional code if you want to catch a failure in a longer chain of commands.

Comment: Great, thanks. This is exactly what I'm looking for. There's just 2 things remaining: is it possible to get an *array* of exit statuses? I guess not, unless you output them and then take the last line of output to mean exit statuses. Am I right? The second thing is how to make this work with shells other than bash (not a hard requirement for me, but a nice-to-have if you know how to).

Comment: Yes, you would have to make the exit status array the "output" instead of the exit status. `PIPESTATUS` is a Bash builtin and I think zsh has it as well. I don't believe any other shells do. So you would have to look for some other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to think of a more generic solution that makes the exit status of **each command** in the pipe available to PHP. Of course it requires a shell with `$PIPESTATUS` (this excludes plain `sh`).

```
// The command with pipes.
$command = 'command1 | command2 | echo Test | gzip -9 -f';

// Execute the command. The overall exit code is in $exitStatus.
exec(
    $command . '; echo -e "\n"${PIPESTATUS[*]}',
    $out,
    $exitStatus
);

// Get the exit statuses and remove them from the output.
$pipeStatus = explode(' ', array_pop($out));

print_r([$pipeStatus, $out]);
// [
//   [
//     "127",
//     "127",
//     "0",
//     "0",
//   ],
//   [
//     b"\x1Fâ€¹\x089fÃ™W\x02I-.Ã¡\x02Ã‚\x1AxÃº\x05",
//   ],
// ]
```

Slightly simpler variant if you're sure the piped commands will end with a newline (notice the `echo` part in the command is different):

```
// The command with pipes.
$command = 'command1 | command2 | echo Testing things | sed s/things/stuff/';

// Execute the command. The overall exit code is in $exitStatus.
exec(
    $command . '; echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}',
    $out,
    $exitStatus
);

// Get the exit statuses and remove them from the output.
$pipeStatus = explode(' ', array_pop($out));

print_r([$pipeStatus, $out]);
// [
//   [
//     "127",
//     "127",
//     "0",
//     "0",
//   ],
//   [
//     "Testing stuff",
//   ],
// ]
```